# filtering dataframe using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can not figure out why I keep getting a type error message when trying to filter a column. I have a datasheet with a variable name of "data" and have a column  names dur_seconds.

It works fine when I write out:

```
data["dur_seconds"] == 600
```

but when I try the following:

```
data["dur_seconds"] > 600
```

I get:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Hopefully someone can help

I change the datatype to  float64 but got the same error message

Hopefully someone can help

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the df.

Comment: Simply , error message is exactly this situation. dont compare str and int. You say you've changed, but it is not changed. Provide simple example for answer, then maybe  you will find cause by yourself before someone answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might store dur_seconds as an object so that it can be compared, but you won't be able to use the int operation.

Check the column type by

```
print(data.dtypes)
```

Alternatively, force the conversion of data in a column to int.

```py
data["dur_seconds"] = data["dur_seconds"].astype(int)
```

Or use pandas.to_numeric. If the data in the column is unconvertible to int, convert it to NaN and replace NaN with 0 or another default value.

```
data["dur_seconds"] = pd.to_numeric(data["dur_seconds"], errors='coerce')
data = data.replace(np.nan, 0, regex=True)
data["dur_seconds"] = data["dur_seconds"].astype(int)
```